# Raspbian - Network Manager maps modem to an ehternet and not PPP interface

Tags: networking, modem, networkmanager, ppp

I have a very interesting problem: I'm trying to achieve cellular connectivity on RPi4, with a modem (Telit LE910C4-EU). For this purpose I'm using modem manager & network manager:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install network-manager
apt-get install modemmanager
reboot
mmcli -m 0 --simple-connect="apn=sphone"
nmcli c add type gsm ifname ttyACM0 con-name cellcom apn sphone
nmcli con up id cellcom
```

This works perfectly on Ubuntu server (latest 20.04), and I get internet connectivity. On Raspbian OS (latest stable release 2020-05-27) on the other hand, with the same Pi, modem & SIM - this is not working!

After investigating this I've noticed that the wwan0 interface on Ubuntu is created by network manager as a POINTTOPOINT interface, while on Raspbian, as plain ehternet interface! Does anyone know why this happens, and how we can change it?

### Raspbian - ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:b1:5a:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 259  bytes 23782 (23.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 259  bytes 23782 (23.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b2:05:a3:5a:38:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.129.78.129  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 10.129.78.131
        inet6 2001:4df7:0:9e68:419:3bba:8e96:a9e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 8a:36:72:11:0c:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 264  bytes 18003 (17.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

### Ubuntu - ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.100.102.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.100.102.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:feb1:5a5e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:b1:5a:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 877  bytes 96168 (96.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 514  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 273  bytes 43483 (43.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 100  bytes 7644 (7.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 100  bytes 7644 (7.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:b1:5a:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwan0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.153.125.200  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 10.153.125.200
        inet6 2a02:14f:1ff:a8ed:618f:e5f2:eb86:9265  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 8  bytes 850 (850.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

### Raspbian - mmcli -m 0:

```
--------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: 4f1ed10242afd5fc1f738ab4dafd23f27ec81eea
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
           |                model: LE910C4-EU
           |             revision: 25.20.673  1  [Dec 11 2018 23:00:00]
           |         h/w revision: 10000
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
           |              drivers: option1, qmi_wwan
           |               plugin: Telit
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: ttyUSB2 (at), cdc-wdm0 (qmi), wwan0 (net), ttyUSB3 (at)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |                 lock: sim-pin2
           |       unlock retries: sim-pin (5), sim-pin2 (5), sim-puk (5), sim-puk2 (5)
           |                state: connected
           |          power state: on
           |          access tech: lte
           |       signal quality: 100% (recent)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |              current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: egsm, dcs, utran-1, utran-3, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, 
           |                       eutran-7, eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28
           |              current: egsm, dcs, utran-1, utran-3, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, 
           |                       eutran-7, eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
           |          operator id: 42502
           |        operator name: Cellcom
           |         registration: home
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-1
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
  --------------------------------
  Bearer   |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/2
```

### Ubuntu - mmcli -m 0:

```
--------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: 4f1ed10242afd5fc1f738ab4dafd23f27ec81eea
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
           |                model: LE910C4-EU
           |    firmware revision: 25.20.673  1  [Dec 11 2018 23:00:00]
           |       carrier config: default
           |         h/w revision: 10000
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
           |              drivers: option1, qmi_wwan
           |               plugin: Telit
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (qmi), ttyUSB2 (at), wwan0 (net), ttyUSB3 (at)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |                 lock: sim-pin2
           |       unlock retries: sim-pin (5), sim-puk (5), sim-pin2 (5), sim-puk2 (5)
           |                state: connected
           |          power state: on
           |          access tech: lte
           |       signal quality: 100% (recent)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |              current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: egsm, dcs, utran-1, utran-3, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, 
           |                       eutran-7, eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28
           |              current: egsm, dcs, utran-1, utran-3, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, 
           |                       eutran-7, eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
           |          operator id: 42502
           |        operator name: Cellcom
           |         registration: home
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-1
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
  --------------------------------
  Bearer   |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0
```

Does anyone has an idea why the different behavior, and how to fix it on Raspbian?

Thanks a lot!

Vitaliy

Comment: check this link (found at random): https://techship.com/faq/how-to-step-by-step-set-up-a-data-connection-over-qmi-interface-using-qmicli-and-in-kernel-driver-qmi-wwan-in-linux/ ("to change qmi_wwan driver to use Raw-IP")

Comment: WOW @A.B!!! This solved it !!! Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: If you want to thank me, write an answer to your own question with the commands you had to use and probably the link I found.

Comment: @A.B I prefer you to have the credit for this answer! Doesn't feel right to me to answer this instead of you.